# how to add content inside FieldSetView and legend while generating android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a login page in which I am using FieldSetView and legend. The problem is when I am adding text field inside this, the text fields are not added properly. It comes outside

[I want the password field inside `fieldsetview`. Here is the output which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BXTB.png)

### Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <libs.mjn.fieldset.FieldSetView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:fsv_borderRadius="8dp"
        app:fsv_borderColor="#062999"
        app:fsv_borderWidth="2dp"
        app:fsv_legend="Sign In"
        app:fsv_legendPosition="left"
        app:fsv_legendSize="16sp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:hint="email"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password"
            android:text="@string/password"

            android:inputType="textPassword"
            />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </libs.mjn.fieldset.FieldSetView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide xml code

Comment: I added the xml which i write can you please help me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout like this

```
<libs.mjn.fieldset.FieldSetView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:fsv_borderColor="#062999"
            app:fsv_borderRadius="8dp"
            app:fsv_borderWidth="2dp"
            app:fsv_legend="Sign In"
            app:fsv_legendPosition="left"
            app:fsv_legendSize="16sp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:text="@string/email" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"

                        android:text="@string/password" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </libs.mjn.fieldset.FieldSetView>
```